# optimizing a system of equation which its variables and parameters are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, partial-derivative, matrix-equations

I have a function, F, to minimize. Let's assume:

$F(X,Y,Z) = G(A-YX)^2 - H(B-ZYY')^2 $

Where $X, Y, Z$ are my unknown variables in a matrix shape, and the matrices $A, B$ are the given ones.

I know all the subjects about necessity and sufficient conditions --taking derivatives, Hermitian matrix and calculating its eigenvalues and etc. But my question is: are the ordinary methods applicable to this equation?

I will be thankful if some hint me how to solve this equation by using the above-mentioned methods.

Besides that, I know that we always try to convert a set of linear equations (some cases nonlinear) into a matrix notation form, but what should we do if we have equations which its parameters are matrices?

Sincerely yours,

Comment: $F(X,Y,Z)$ is not scalar at all! So how do you define extrema?

Comment: It would be better to think of it as Partial Differential Equation system instead of an ordinary optimization problem.